# how to "re-validate" a foreign constraint in oracle

Tags: oracle

I have a foreign constraint as below. This was created like three years ago. All the data that are created after this constraint are valid but the backlog data (data before three years) are not valid. Toad shows this constraint as 'Not Validated'

```
ALTER TABLE ISSUES ADD (
  CONSTRAINT FK_CLIENT 
 FOREIGN KEY (CLIENT) 
 REFERENCES REPORTERS(USERID)
    DEFERRABLE INITIALLY DEFERRED);
```

Today i fixed all the backlog data and now this constraint will hold good both for existing as well as new data. But how will i make the constraint as 'Validated'.

Is there any way to 're-validate' a foreign constraint?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You should be able to:

```
ALTER TABLE issues ENABLE VALIDATE CONSTRAINT fk_client;
```

Comment: Forgive the space in the command, it gets the post by the SQL injection detector

Comment: @DCookie - just out of interest, to what SQL injection detector are you referring?

Comment: @Jeffrey Kemp: It's on the firewall at work. Any outgoing web traffic that contains DDL gets blocked, and I can't post it. I don't know exactly what product they use.